# flex 4.6 : Application crash if no internet connection

Tags: wcf, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

My mobile application is interact with WCF web services i build it in flash builder with Data/Services then put the url in the WSDL services 
my issue is if the mobile starts with no internet connection it crashed
the error message in the console

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::rawChildren_getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2187]
at mx.managers::SystemRawChildrenList/getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemRawChildrenList.as:181]
at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/getFormIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:1956]
at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/findTopmostForm()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:1933]
at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/updateProxyImageForTopmostForm()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:2172]
at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:1510]
at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:950]
at mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManagerImpl.as:382]
at mx.managers::PopUpManager$/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManager.as:193]
at spark.components::SkinnablePopUpContainer/open()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\SkinnablePopUpContainer.as:450]
at debug.ondevice.util::EnterDebugHostIPDialog/show()[/ndepot/fb_46_release_branch/ide_builder/com.adobe.flashbuilder.launching.multiplatform.contributor/utilswcs/src/debug/ondevice/util/EnterDebugHostIPDialog.mxml:47]
at debug.ondevice.util::DebuggerHostInfo$/showIPErrorDialog()[/ndepot/fb_46_release_branch/ide_builder/com.adobe.flashbuilder.launching.multiplatform.contributor/utilswcs/src/debug/ondevice/util/DebuggerHostInfo.as:129]
at mx.netmon::NetworkMonitorImpl/ioErrorHandler()[/ndepot/fb_46_release_branch/ide_builder/com.adobe.flexbuilder.monitors.network/netmonlibrary/src/mx/netmon/NetworkMonitorImpl.as:645]
```

i want to handle this error with message if no connection
i tried to put condition for internet connection when creation complete

```
            protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'));
            monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, announceStatus);
            monitor.start();
        }

        public function announceStatus(e:StatusEvent):void {
            trace("Status change. Current status: " + monitor.available);
            (new AlertMsg()).open(this, false) ;
        }
```

but it doesn't reached if no connection

Note : My target is android

Thanks in advance , for any help

Comment: IT is not obvious to me from the stack trace whether the error comes from your own code or from Flash.  But, you can probably handle the error with an uncaughtException handler.  But, that may  just hide the symptom and not solve the underlying problem.

Comment: how to use uncaughtException ? (in which line)
the error comes from flash files i think it in SystemManger.as in the method   mx_internal function rawChildren_getChildIndex(child:DisplayObject):int
 { return super.getChildIndex(child); }
and it require to pass child for use in another method 
Give me the advice to how to use uncaughtException  or pass fake (child) in the parameter

Comment: Read this about the global exception handler: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/global-exception-handling.html

Comment: I'm not sure your error is because of the internet connection failure, anyways you have to periodically check the internet connection by setting the pollInterval value to the url monitor Eg:-monitor.pollInterval = 30000; so that it will trigger the status event periodically.